# TFS on Windows 7 64bit: reasons for it hanging

Tags: windows-7, team-foundation-server

Since I installed TFS on Windows 7 64 bit, I can't figure out why it very often hangs, with apparently no reason:

- no evident anomaly on task manager or procexp: CPU usage rate low, a lot of free memory
- Event Viewer is empty

Did anyone else experience this?
How can I improve the performance of the system?

Comment: Some things to try.  Disable anti-virus.  Reinstall TFS.  Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: @murisonc Antivirus disabled, TFS 2010

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue with TFS where it would hang and become unresponsive.

I found a solution to this by updating the tf.exe.config or devenv.exe.config file with the following configuration values.

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
        <add address="*" maxconnection="1000"/>
    </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

I set the limit to 1000 on my side, as i carefully watched the value in Resource Monitor, though truthfully i never got higher than 600 concurrent connections.

Answer (score 1):

Fire up [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), find your hung process and try and work out what it's blocked on. It will hopefully give you some pointers to the underlying cause.

Comment: with _procexp_ I meant Process Explorer.

Comment: If you have never used any of the Sysinternals tools before I would take a look at Mark Russinovich's webcast Case of the unexplained found here: http://bit.ly/hIWIM0.  It has some great problem solving logic using the sysinternals tools